# Question about subgroups of a symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I have the following question:

For $n\ge 5$ show that the symmetric group $S_n$ cannot have a subgroup $H$ with $3\le [S_n:H]< n$. ($[S_n:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $S_n$).

This is technically not a homework question, since it's from one of the past qual exams, but still I would prefer to get a hint, rather than full solution.

What did I get thus far: suppose $ [S_n:H]=k$, then $|H|=\frac{n!}{k}$. Then by counting argument I proved that $|A_n\cap H|\ge \frac{n!}{2k}$, so either $|A_n\cap H|= \frac{n!}{2k}$ or $H\le A_n$. But here I stuck.

So I have two questions:

1) Am I on the right track? If so, what I should do next?

2) If not, where I should start?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Cayley's theorem, or the refined version which says that if a group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of finite index $k,$ there is a homomorphism $\phi: G \to S_{k}$ such that ${\rm ker} \phi$ is  normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$ (in fact, the largest such)?

Comment: I'm not convinced the premise is correct.  Consider $H = \{e, (1 2)\}$.  Then $[S_n:H] = \frac{n!}{2}$, which is certainly greater than $3$ in sufficiently large symmetric groups.  I'm sure I'm being pretty dense somewhere, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @KajHansen The problem says $[S_n:H]<n$, but $\frac{n!}{2}<n$ iff $n<3$.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I was reading "$<n!$" for some reason.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I'm not familiar with this refined version, but I'll look it up, thanks!

Comment: @NurdinTakenov You may not have to look it up. Consider the left action of $G$ on the set of left cosets of $H.$